# Getting Max and Min Values in Crystal Report Formula

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, crystal-reports

I am Using Crystal Report with VS 2012 with Dataset and Populating the Report with Run Time. 
I am getting Repetitive rows for My Report, It is because the Data is Entered with Different Period (Month/Year) like the salary of Person for Month and Year. 
So What I thought to get rid of the Repetition of rows is I am going to Get the Values of Summarized (Group footer) portion of a Particular Employee instead of GETTING DETAIL SECTION where Every record repeats instead of Period. I have achieved it, But the Problem is the Minimum Function is not getting the accurate Minimum Period as Shown the picture.  [image]
The formula for I which I used to Show Minimum and Maximum period values is:

```
 Maximum ({DataTable1.Period}, {DataTable1.PPO_NO})&" - "& Minimum ({DataTable1.Period}, {DataTable1.PPO_NO})
```

and My Formula for getting Employee Month and Year are:

```
SELECT PPONO, Name, Father_Name,Designation,BPS,Claimant,Age,Type,IOT,  TblPPOBook.Pay_Month + '/' + CAST(TblPPOBook.Pay_Year AS nvarchar(4)) AS Period, Pension, Allow etc. From EmployeeTable Where PayDate Between Date1 ANd Date2.
```

The Early help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Comment: what is datatype of period? string or date?

Comment: String, Infact it is consisting of Two String Columns merged with Query. One Column is for Month and other one is for Year and then I merge it with query.

Comment: Try converting to date and then apply min and max functions

Comment: I did it with CDate but out of luck.

Comment: can you show me the output of CDate.. it should work and also where did you use the converted date from string?

Comment: It is missing 11/2015 and gives me 12/2015 as Minimum Value. And If there would have been 08/2015,092015,10/2015,11/2015,12/2015,01/2016,02/2016 and then It returns also 12/2015 instead of getting 08/2015.

Comment: 'cdate( Maximum ({DataTable1.Period}, {DataTable1.PPO_NO}))&" - "&cdate( Minimum ({DataTable1.Period}, {DataTable1.PPO_NO}))'

Comment: No I am asing when you convert to date then what is the output?

Comment: this is wrong interpretation `'( Maximum (CDate({DataTable1.Period}, {DataTable1.PPO_NO})))&" - "&( Minimum (CDate({DataTable1.Period}, {DataTable1.PPO_NO})))`... this is correct way of checking min and max

Comment: sorry this needs to be changed further... `( Maximum ((CDate({DataTable1.Period}), {DataTable1.PPO_NO})))&" - "&( Minimum ((CDate({DataTable1.Period}), {DataTable1.PPO_NO})))`

Comment: didn't check the syntax check closing and opening braces of the formula and provide appropriately

Comment: I tried every thing, I mean by changing places of braces, but still failed. Plz help. thanks.

Comment: can you post changed formula once also please post the design screenshot let me look at the fields where you have placed in report

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a formula to convert string to date i.e

@String to date:= Datevar Date_Period:=CDate({Period});

Second use this formula to find min and max date i.e

Maximum ({@String to date}, {PPO No#})& " to " & Minimum ({@String to date}, {PPO No#}) ;